# Vim: How to jump to first/last line of the current paragraph?

Tags: vim

With `{` and `}` I can jump to the start/end of the paragraph (empty lines), but how to go to first/last line of the paragraph instead?

Answer (score 16):

Go to the start of the first word of a paragraph: `{w`

Go to the end of the last word of a paragraph: `}ge`

Comment: Works quite well in most cases, thank you! Fails only when the paragraph's first line contains just one word and is also the first line of the buffer, or similarly when the paragraph's last line contains just one word and is also the last line of the buffer.

Answer (score 6):

Map some new commands:

Start of first line of paragraph:

```
:map f {)
```

Start of last line of paragraph:

```
:map l }(
```

Then use `f` and `l` to navigate. You might want to choose alternate keys.

Comment: Even if you limited it to normal mode, why would you want to override f and l's default behavior? Surely, pick something else, and use nnoremap instead. I'd go with {j and }k instead as well.

Comment: You probably wouldn't want to remap those keys, but I did say "You might want to choose alternate keys" :-)

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression there must be special motion commands I weren't aware of. As for combinations of motions to achieve that, thanks for the suggestions, but they don't work that well. `{)` does work unless the paragraph's first line is also the first line of the buffer. `}(` doesn't work e.g. if the paragraph doesn't contain sentence terminators, or if the last sentence doesn't start on the last line.

Comment: @frabjous: Thanks, `{j` and `}k` do work better, but still they aren't perfect either. The former won't do it if the paragraph's first line is the first line of the buffer, likewise the latter won't do it if the paragraph's last line is the last line of the buffer.

Comment: I would rather use `noremap` or `nnoremap`. Particularly if the author would remap `{` or `}` to `{j` and `}k`.

Comment: Does not work if there is no empty line before or after the paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

I can only suggest

```
set whichwrap+=b,s
set virtualedit=onemore
nnoremap { k{<Space>0
vnoremap { k{<Space>0
nnoremap } j}<BS>0
vnoremap } j}<BS>0
```

(edited).

Comment: What't the purpose of `whichwrap` and `virtualedit` settings here?  The remappings seem to work fine without them.

Comment: we can't go  to the very last line of the file with this thaw

Comment: @EmmanuelMericdeBellefon [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62365335/1640661)  deals with the case where the last line of the paragraph is the last line of the buffer

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to be able to do something similar (programmatically convert the lines of the current paragraph to an ordered or unordered list) using Vimscript. Dealing with the cases where the first line of the current paragraph is also the first line of the current buffer (or the last line of the paragraph is the last line of the buffer) was problematic and took a few hours to solve.

To answer this question, I adapted the functions I came up with to solve my problem by modifying them to move the cursor instead of returning a line number. Note that my solution preserves the column position of the cursor but that may not be necessary.

```
function! MoveParagraphFirstLine()
  let column = col(".")
  let first_line = line("'{")
  " Detect if the first line of the current paragraph is also the first line
  " of the current buffer and move cursor position accordingly.
  if first_line == 1
    call cursor(1, column)
  else
    call cursor(first_line + 1, column)
  endif
endfunction

function! MoveParagraphLastLine()
  let column = col(".")
  let last_line = line("'}")
  " Detect if the last line of the paragraph is also last line of the buffer.
  if line("$") == last_line
    call cursor(last_line, column)
  else
    call cursor(last_line - 1, column)
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>f :call MoveParagraphFirstLine()<CR>
nnoremap <leader>l :call MoveParagraphLastLine()<CR>
```